# How do I take values from textboxes and add them?

Tags: java, textfield

I'm trying to code a Java program to take two values from a GUI and add them using text boxes and an add button. I know I have to use actionlisteners and use something to actually get the values from the textboxes, but I'm not quite sure where that all fits into the code that I already have. I've been working on it for about a few hours and just can't figure it out. I have posted what I have so far below, any help would be greatly appreciated!

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

public class Add extends JFrame {
    JLabel num1Label = new JLabel("Number 1: ", JLabel.CENTER); //NUM1LABEL
    JTextField num1Name = new JTextField(15);                   //NUM1BOX
    JLabel num2Label = new JLabel("Number 2: ", JLabel.CENTER); //NUM2LABEL
    JTextField num2Name = new JTextField(15);                   //NUM2BOX
    JButton exitButton = new JButton("Add");                    //ADDBUTTON

    public Add() {
        super("Actions");
        setSize(400, 200);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        GridLayout grid = new GridLayout(3,3);
        setLayout(grid);
        add(num1Label);
        add(num1Name);
        add(num2Label);
        add(num2Name);
        add(exitButton);
        setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] arguments) {
        Add ag = new Add();
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you have a question, or are you just being a help vampire? Please describe your problem in detail so it can be easily answered.

Comment: Ok, my problem is that I don't know how to grab the values entered from the text boxes and add them to get a result. It may seem like a beginner question to you but its really not making sense.

Comment: Getting the values and adding them are two different questions. "Please help me" is not a question.

Comment: Alright sorry about that. I'm new to Java programming and needed some help. Didn't mean to offend anyone.

Comment: Offend? I'm not offended. Anyway, you should see the [About page](http://stackoverflow.com/about) and [FAQ](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7931/faq-for-stack-exchange-sites).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer your question in the title...

You need to get the text within the textboxes and parse it as a number:

```
int num1 = Integer.parseInt(num1Name.getText());
int num2 = Integer.parseInt(num2Name.getText());
int result = num1 + num2;
num3Name.setText(Integer.toString(result));
```

where `num3Name` is a `JTextField` (which you can use to store your result)

This can at least point you in the right direction.